# How to update HTML object data and type through Javascript in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, html

I have declared an object in HTML using the following code:

```
<object type="text/plain" id="clueBox" data="clues/random.txt" height="315" width="560"></object>
```

And then in my Javascript I have a function that looks like this:

```
function dummy(){
    var box = document.getElementById("clueBox");

    //alert(currentClue + " " + clueTypes[clueNum]);
    box.setAttribute("type", "text/plain");
    box.setAttribute("data", "clues/clue0.txt");
    alert("Called Dummy");

}
```

Calling this function is supposed to update the clueBox object in the HTML. It works flawlessly in Firefox, but doesn't work at all in Safari. I need to make it work in Safari. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: How/where are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

I did not have a problem with your code. I would check your error console in Safari and see if there may be a javascript error. You can open it by pressing Ctrl+Alt+C. Also is your alert getting fired?